# When do cobordism groups depend on differential structure?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology, mp.mathematical-physics, cobordism

I heard that cobordism group with structures sometimes depend on differential structure of space.
Do you know any examples or references about this facts?

I want to know when difference occur between cobordism group with difference structure (and other structure) and cobordism group "without" differential structure.

Comment: I thought that cobordism groups satisfy the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms and those include the homotopy axiom?

Comment: Please could you edit your post to ask a precise mathematical question? There may be an interesting question here, but at the moment it's difficult to know what is being asked.

Comment: To elaborate on @ThiKu's comment. An element of the cobordism group of a topological space is represented by a map from a manifold into that space. And two such representatives are the same if one can find a cobordism between the source-manifolds and extend the map. So we do not need any additional (e.g. smooth) structure on the target to define its cobordism groups and any homotopy equivalence between the target spaces induces an isomorphism on cobordism groups. 
The key point is that even if the target space happens to be a manifold, there are no assumptions on the map.

Comment: I concur with Mark Grant.  Your language is far too vague.  Please be specific on what "cobordism group with difference structure (and other structure)" means.  Are you talking about Thom-Milnor style cobordism groups, i.e. things like spin cobordism, or something entirely different?

Answer (score 5):

In principle, cobordism groups should always depend on the differential structure, as a priori there is no reason why homeomorphic but not diffeomorphic smooth manifolds should be cobordant. So what should be surprising is rather the opposite, e.g., that all of the 28 exotic 7-dimensional spheres are actually cobordant. Adding structure, e.g., a reduction or lift of the structure group of the tangent bundle of the manifold to a higly connected cover of the orthogonal group, this dependence from the smooth structure becomes manifest. An example are the cobordism groups of string manifolds, that can be found on the Manifold Atlas: http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/String_bordism#The_bordism_groups

Comment: Sorry for my question was unclear. My question is when difference occur between cobordism group with difference structure (and other structure) and cobordism group "without" differential structure.

Comment: Not sure I correctly understand the question: what should cobordims without differential structure be? A possible interpretation is: "does the cobordism class (with structure) only depend on the underlying topological structure of a smooth manifold?"  and this is what I tried to answer.

Comment: Actually, I am interested in classification of SPT phases. SPT phase is physics object but its classification can be understood through pure mathematical theory. According to https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.06527 , SPT phases can be classifyed by cobordism theory. Some examples which physicists need are included in https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.11967 . So my interest is that is there any examples which $\Omega^H(BG)$ differ if $H$ involves differential structure. ($H$ is structure and G is a group which represents the symmetry of the theory.)

Comment: @TakamasaAndo $H$ matters a lot. For example, if $H$ is a _complex structure_ on the stable normal bundle of the manifold, then $\Omega^H(BG)$ is _torsion-free_, when $G$ is the trivial group. On the other hand, if $H$ is instead a _framing_ on the stable normal bundle of the manifold, then $\Omega^H(BG)$ is isomorphic to the stable homotopy groups of spheres, when $G$ is the trivial group. So it's all _torsion_ in positive degrees. Much of the 1979 book "The classifying spaces for surgery and cobordism of manifolds" by Madsen and Milgram is devoted to these issues.

Comment: For oriented cobordism it is the case that topologically cobordant implies smooth cobordant. This is because the bordism class depends only on the SW and Pontryagin numbers which miraculously only depend on the homeomorphism type of the manifold, but as you say this is certainly not obvious.